# Java regex question: How to match a sting from N-th field in a line using regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match string "RAV" on every line on 15th word. Each word is delimited by "`|`" (pipe). I need to compare if line has this string or not. If yes, I will proceed with my next step.

I was trying this

```
((((?:[^|]*\|){17}(.*?)\|)+\|[^|]*$)|[^|]+(?=(\,\H\,))|(^([0-9]){4})|(([RAV]){3}))
```

But this one matches even if I have "RAV" first, second or any other fields.

I need to match exactly on 15th field.

Comment: BTW, following checks any field containing "RAV"   (^(?:[^|]*\|){17}([^|]*)+\|[^|]*$)|[^,]+(?=(\,\H\,))|(^([0-9]){4})|(([RAV]){3})

Comment: can there be more then just "RAV" in the 15th word? or is it like "...|RAV|..."? I'm asking because you could just spit the line by `|` and then use a regular string comparison with equals.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the first 14 words, and then capture the 15th word after the pipe.

If you want to prevent a partial word, you can always append a word boundary `(RAV)\b`

```
^(?:\w+\|){14}(RAV)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glhdyv/1)

Or using a negated character class, but that can match more that 1 word between the pipes:

```
^(?:[^|]+\|){14}(RAV)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FtiXbV/1)

Comment: Don't have to capture RAV because it's a constant (any code using it can use `RAV` instead of group 1). And pipe is more definite than word boundary in case "word" has non letters like `"don't"`, and OP has `17` in regex, so we know there's another column following, so `^(?:[^|]+\|){14}RAV\|`. plus it's canonical.

Comment: It is not returning this pattern. 
String is 
"8/23/2022 7:35:08 AM|33224455|DF My-Store|ABCD-OY-MMNNYYDD|98121928|DF|FNU LNU|1234 ISLAND COVE CT|DELTA LAKE|CT|98765-8470||73023|MIS|MIS VAR DISPLAY|RAV||MYDF'"
As you see 15th field has string "RAV".

I need get this pattern "RAV" from 15th field.
I tried following 
"'(^(?:[^|]*\|){15}([^|]*)+\|[^|]*$)|[^,]+(?=(\,\H\,))|(^([0-9]){4})|(([RAV]){3})'". 
This fetch pattern "RAV" from any field. That is the issue. I need to check 15th field specifically and then match it with "RAV"

let me know. Thanks